# How do I find the sum of a geometric series if it doesn't seem consistent?

Tags: calculus, geometric-series

I'm supposed to find the sum of the geometric series $$S= 9 + x + x^2 + x^3 + ...$$
I have no idea how to do this, since if I'm to follow the general pattern of infinite geometric series, it should be $$a + ax + ax^2 +......$$and so on, but the 9 doesn't fit since if the $x$ is $x/9$, the third term would be $x^2/9$ and so on. What do I do for this?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  $9+x+x^2+x^3+\cdots=(8)+(1+x+x^2+x^3+\cdots)$

Comment: Try writing $9 = 8+1$ and see if you can use the formula then.

Comment: I tried the answer 9 + 1/(1-x) for the sum, but it didn't like it. Should I have tried 8 instead of 9, since 8+1 = 9?

Comment: yes, $9+1/(1-x)=9+1+x+x^2+\cdots=10+x+x^2+\cdots,$ which is not what you want

Comment: Thank you for the help! I was thinking about it slightly wrong, so that worked!

Comment: Or first find of the sum of the terms omitting the $9$, and then add $9$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simpler than you're thinking it is. The form you desire to pop up (at least in order to make some nice simplifications) is

$$1+x+x^2+x^3+\cdots$$

right? What would happen if you added $8$ to it? You would get

$$8+(1+x+x^2+x^3+\cdots)$$

or, equivalently,

$$9+x+x^2+x^3+\cdots$$

That is, these last two expressions are equivalent! The middle expression, provided $|x|<1$, lets us convert the infinite summation to a ratio in the usual way as well:

$$8+(1+x+x^2+x^3+\cdots) = 8 + \frac{1}{1-x}$$